# Why can't I declare the dataframe type object when I apply inplace = True

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've tried to `dataFrame.interpolate(inplace=True)` and `dataFrame.fillna(0, inplace=True)` by referring original and new dataframe object.

Ex)

```
train = train.interpolate(inplace=True)
test = test.fillna(inplace=True)

train.info()
```

When I do this, the error is occurred **'NoneType' object has no attribute 'info'** .
I know `inplace=True` option means that original dataframe's data change.
So, I'm wondering why I can't do this and how can I do if I want to newDataFrame = originalDataFrame.fillna(inplace = True).

Answer (score 1):

You correctly understand the purpose of `inplace`: it modifies the dataframe directly instead of returning a new one. However, it also **does not return anything** if `inplace=True`.

So you either want to not reassign:

```
train.interpolate(inplace=True)
test.fillna(inplace=True)
```

Or not use `inplace=True` (this is generally prefered; I believe the `inplace` option is being considered for deprecation globally):

```
train = train.interpolate()
test = test.fillna()
```

And then `test.info()` will work as expected.